# Windows 10 important updates needed(blue screen)

Tags: windows, windows-10, updates

Any idea how to prevent Windows 10 important updates blue screen? It happens often and when I click "Not right now" sometimes my laptop become laggy and I need to wait 4-5 minutes before the pop-up disappears.

Tomorrow I have to present a school project from my laptop and it will be awkward. I don't have time or space to update. I tried to stop update service but that didn't help

[image]

Comment: This screen cannot be prevented.  So I suggest you bring up your machine, well in advance of your presentation, or simply upgrade your machine.

Comment: Which exact Windows version are you on at the moment?

Comment: @harrymc - Based on the April 10th, 2018 date, the only version that is no longer supported as of that date, means the author is running Windows 10 1607.

Comment: Use another PC for your presentation.